# Flutter. How to disable "Double tap to activate, double tap and hold to long press" hint in accessibility mode

Tags: flutter, dart, accessibility

Currently, I'm working with Accessibility in Flutter and on android devices it's pronouncing this hint: *"double tap to activate, double tap and hold to long press"*.
As far as I know this hint pronounced if widget is clickable, so I tried wrapping child of this widget with **BlockSemantics** (didn't work), also wrapped this clickable widget with **Semantics** and set property **button: false** but that also didn't help.
This how my widget looks.

```
  return GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTap: () => widget.onItemSelect(),
        onLongPress: () => widget.onItemLongPress(),
        child: childWidget,
       );
```

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GestureDetector** has a ***excludeSemantics*** property, so I set it to ***true***. It will NOT block child widget's semantics, it will just disable semantics for GestureDetector widget itself, and as a result Android accessibility hint also turn off